# Solving eigenvalue linear system with Fortran using Lapack zggev routine

Tags: fortran, lapack, eigenvalue

I am trying to use the ZGGEV routine from Lapack to solve the general eigen value problem, namely, **A** **x**=**v** **B** **x**. Where **v** is the eigen-value. I'm doing a small test on some random matrixes. Let's say

```
A=[ -21.10-22.50i   53.50-50.50i    -34.50+127.50i  7.50+0.50i;
    -0.46-7.78i    -3.50-37.50i    -15.50+58.50i    -10.50-1.50i;   
     4.30-5.50i 39.70-17.10i    -68.50+12.50i   -7.50-3.50i;    
      5.50+4.40i    14.40+43.30i    -32.50-46.00i   -19.00-32.50i]

B=[   1.00-5.00i    1.60+1.20i  -3.00+0.00i 0.00-1.00i  ;
      0.80-0.60i    3.00-5.00i  -4.00+3.00i -2.40-3.20i ;
      1.00+0.00i    2.40+1.80i  -4.00-5.00i 0.00-3.00i  ;
      0.00+1.00i    -1.80+2.40i 0.00-4.00i  4.00-5.00i]
```

my Fortran codes are as followed:
         program testz

```
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: N=4, nb=64, Nmax=10
  integer :: lda,ldb,ldvr,lwork
  parameter (lda=Nmax, ldb=Nmax, ldvr=Nmax,lwork=Nmax+Nmax*nb)
  integer :: i,j,info
  complex(kind=16) :: A(lda,Nmax), alpha(Nmax), B(ldb,Nmax),
 &     beta(Nmax), dummy(1,1), vr(ldvr,Nmax), work(lwork), eig(Nmax)
  double precision :: rwork(8*Nmax)


  A(1,1)=(-21.10,-22.50);A(1,2)=(53.50,-50.50)
  A(1,3)=(-34.50,127.50);A(1,4)=(7.50,0.50)
  A(2,1)=(-0.46,7.78);A(2,2)=(-3.5,-37.5)
  A(2,3)=(-15.5,58.5);A(2,4)=(-10.5,-1.5)
  A(3,1)=(4.3,-5.5);A(3,2)=(39.7,-17.1)
  A(3,3)=(-68.5,12.5);A(3,4)=(-7.5,-3.5)
  A(4,1)=(5.5,4.4);A(4,2)=(14.4,43.3)
  A(4,3)=(-32.5,-46);A(4,4)=(-19,32.5)
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  B(1,1)=(1,-5);B(1,2)=(1.6,1.2)
  B(1,3)=(-3,0);B(1,4)=(0,-1)
  B(2,1)=(0.8,-0.6);B(2,2)=(3,-5)
  B(2,3)=(-4,3);B(2,4)=(-2.4,-3.2)
  B(3,1)=(1,0);B(3,2)=(2.4,1.8)
  B(3,3)=(-4,-5);B(3,4)=(0,-3)
  B(4,1)=(0,1);B(4,2)=(-1.8,2.4)
  B(4,3)=(0,-4);B(4,4)=(4,-5)
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  call zggev('n','v',N,A,lda,B,ldb,alpha,beta,dummy,1,vr,ldvr,
 &     work,lwork,rwork,info)

  eig=alpha/beta

  !here skip the heading to the file



  do j=1,N   
     write(7,12) eig(j)
12   format('(',2F8.4,')')!,'(',2F8.4,')','(',2F8.4,')','(',2F8.4,')')
  end do  


  end program
```

my results are:
(     NaN     NaN)
(****************)
(  0.0000  0.0000)
(  0.0000  0.0000)
while the correct answer should be
 Eigenvalue( 1) = ( 3.0000E+00,-9.0000E+00)

Eigenvalue( 2) = ( 2.0000E+00,-5.0000E+00)

Eigenvalue( 3) = ( 3.0000E+00,-1.0000E+00)

Eigenvalue( 4) = ( 4.0000E+00,-5.0000E+00)

Comment: hmm the sign of some input seems different... A(2,1)=(-0.46,7.78) -> (-0.46,-7.78) ... A(4,4)=(-19,32.5) -> (-19,-32.5) ... and also complex(kind=16) -> complex(kind=8)

Comment: Yeah...my bad. The number itself does not affect very much, but once I change the kind=16 to kind=8. It works! Thank you!

Comment: This is a "gotcha" I've seen arise for a lot of people using lapack -- it's very important that you use the correct data type for all inputs even when you want to pass a value of zero or one etc. The basic issue is that because there's no interface provided for the routines there is no type checking done for you. (Of course this isn't lapack specific)

Comment: Worth noting there *are* interfaces available. People just don't use them. I never call things like `zgeev`, `cgeev`,... , but always the generic `geev`. https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-geev or http://www.netlib.org/lapack95/DOC/la_geev.txt or one can easily make his own generic interface